# Trying to optimize an earlier "Konami code" function

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to update my existing code (that works):

```
var codeLog = [];
var codeSucc = ["ArrowUp", "ArrowUp", "ArrowDown", "ArrowDown", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "b", "a", "Enter"];

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    codeLog.push(e.key);
    console.log(codeLog);
    if (codeLog.toString() == codeSucc.toString()){
        alert("Konami Code entered, enter the secret page");
        window.open("https://www.google.com", "_self");
        codeLog = [];
    };
});
```

to a version that wastes less "keylogging". My plan has been to only start part of the function when the ArrowUp key has been hit, have it continue logging and pushing to an array until it reaches 11 (the length of the code), then exit out of that and compare that initial array to an established array containing the correct code. The current work I've done on that second part is below, though unfortunately it's stopped logging keys and started bringing up "page is slowing down your browser" windows now:

```
var codeLog = [];
var codeSucc = ["ArrowUp", "ArrowUp", "ArrowDown", "ArrowDown", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "b", "a", "Enter"];

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){ 
    codeLog.push(e.key);
    if (codeLog[0] == "ArrowUp"){ 
        while (codeLog.length != 11){ 
            document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
                codeLog.push(e.key);
            });
        }; 
        if (codeLog.toString() == codeSucc.toString()){
            alert("You entered the code");
        };
    
}; 
});
```

Any potential help would be very appreciated. Thanks much

Comment: _"...a version that wastes less "keylogging""_ - Your version adds an infinite amount of `keydown` event handlers and doesn't do anything else - if the first key you hit is `ArrowUp`

Comment: If you not hit `ArrowUp` as the first key, you "only" store every hit key in `codeLog` which makes it a primitive keylogger

Comment: So the first version is better? Would it be considered sufficient for the task of taking in a "code" or does it need a lot more work?

Comment: _"So the first version is better?"_ - It's the only one that "works" o.O

Answer (score 0):

As noted by other users, in the second version you add an infinite amount of event listeners for the `keydown` event. This occurs as a result of the `while (codeLog.length != 11)` line, which is an infinite loop. When the code enters the loop, it checks the length of `codeLog`, sees that it's not 11, adds an event listener and restarts the loop. This takes place in a fraction of a second, so during the few seconds between each key press, many thousands of event listeners would be created, slowing the page down.

To prevent the endless keylogging that you want to avoid, it would be worth to check the length of the `codeLog` array within the keydown event listener. If it surpasses the length of `codeSucc` then the code is wrong, and `codeLog` can be reset.

This is all well and good, but what happens if the user makes a mistake in the code, and restarts it. They could be half way through the combination (`codeLog.length == 6`) but they start again. This would misalign the code that the user is entering and what the program is checking. To fix this, the code should check if the right key is pressed each time, rather than just at the end.

If we put this all together, it looks like this:

```js
let codeSucc = ["ArrowUp", "ArrowUp", "ArrowDown", "ArrowDown", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "b", "a", "Enter"];
let nextKey = 0;

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.key == codeSucc[nextKey]) {
        // Key is correct! Prepare for the next one
        nextKey++;

        if (nextKey == codeSucc.length) {
            // All the keys are correct!
            alert("Konami Code entered, enter the secret page");
            window.open("https://www.google.com", "_self");
            nextKey = 0;
        }
    } else {
        // Key was wrong, reset everything
        nextKey = 0;
    }
});
```